# IIS Express C# asp dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am testing a simple dll using visual studio 2013 debugger.  The Web setting is setup to use IIS Express to load up a page that accesses the dll.  Everything works fine when I output the dll to the default /bin directory.  When I output the dll to bin/x64 directory the page is not able to load up properly using the VS2013 debugger.  The ONLY change I made is output the dll to the bin/x64 directory as opposed to the bin directory.  I tried specifying:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="x64" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

in the web.config but that doesn't work either.

When I goto:
C:\Users...\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

I see the entry for the virtual directory:

```
<site name="MyApp" id="7">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\MyP\Working" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:27427:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

and that specifies the correct working directory.  I am assuming ASP is picking the dll by default from bin sub directory of the working directory of the project.  I guess the question becomes:

How do I tell IISEXpress / ASP  to pick the dll from a subdirecotry of bin i.e. bin/x64.

Truly appreciate any guidance in this matter.  I have exhausted my resources.  Thanks,

Comment: I am starting to believe that IIS Express ignores or mishandles the <probing> tag in the web.config. any pointers helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because IIS Express only looks in the bin subdirectory of the root for the website.  The probing tag doesn't work for IIS Express.

I have reported the problem to Microsoft.

Hope this saves other people some time.